# Как из xterm сказать окну xterm, чтобы оно встало поверх всех окон и в фокусе?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

Как из [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/) сказать окну xterm, чтобы оно встало поверх всех окон и в фокусе?

Гуглил, читаю маны про tput, stty, но не могу найти.

Или это средствами самого xterm не сделать? Тогда через gnome-manager какой-нибудь?

Comment: Оно? [FVWM: Make xterm stay on top, conditionally](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197742)

Comment: Или вот это: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/starting-an-xterm-window-that-is-always-on-top-on-command-line-370315/

Answer (score 1):

можно, например, воспользоваться программой *wmctrl* из одноимённого пакета:

```
$ wmctrl -a имя-окна
```

имя окна можно узнать, запустив программу *xwininfo*, и щёлкнув по интересующему окну. пример:

```
$ xwininfo 

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0xff87aa "Terminal"
...
```

имя окна в данном случае — `Terminal`.

правда, в таком случае будут «притянуты наверх» все окна, имеющие такое имя. но можно адресоваться к конкретному окну по его идентификатору (в примере — `0xff87aa`):

```
$ wmctrl -i -a 0xff87aa
```

---

аналогично эффекта можно добиться и с помощью программы *xdotool* (из одноимённого пакета):

```
$ xdotool windowactivate 0xff87aa
```

Comment: Это, конечно, здорово. А без кликов руками как-то можно (lsof или что-то в этом духе, да хоть gdb) узнать id окна, зная pid?

Comment: @avp, насколько я знаю, нет. ваш вопрос, с моей точки зрения, с некоторой долей условности, можно отождествить с вопросом: можно ли по pid процесса узнать, какие изменения в файловой системе проделал **ранее** данный процесс.

Comment: Интересное сравнение. Я, понятно, не буду этим заниматься, но чисто теоретически, у нас же есть файловый дескриптор, ведущий к Х-серверу и в принципе с помощью gdb можно форкнуть приаттаченный процесс и запустить в потомке свою программу, унаследовав этот дескриптор ... (уже лет 20 в иксах ничего не писал).

Comment: @avp, ну, да, дескриптор, конечно, есть. именно через него общаются x-клиенты (через вызовы xlib) с x-сервером. в послнее время — обычно файловый (общение через tcp ввиду проблематичности аутентификации клиентов средствами x-сервера признано небезопасным и его можно встретить разве что в некоторых реализациях «тонких клиентов»).