# Ограничить использование процессора всем процессам запущеным в VNC сессии

Tags: linux, cpu, limit

Требуется ограничить использование CPU для всего что запущенно в VNC сессии(граф. оболочка, приложения), так чтоб все запущенное в ней в суме использовало процессор максимум на n%, cgroups это позволяет я так понимаю.
С помощу какой утилуты можно сделать это?

Comment: Эм... может я отстал от жизни, но внутри vnc разве что-то можно запустить? Это же вроде как отдельная штука, которая просто транслит изображение и немного i\o.

Comment: @donRumata, как я понимаю, вопрос сводится к поиску всех процессов, которые хоть раз подключались в качестве x-клиентов к указанному экземпляру x-сервера. см., например, дискуссию под [этим ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524704/178576).